# What kind of discussion lists exist that are used by researchers?

Tags: email, research

I have to create a mailing list. One of those kinds that are used in academia, with just one address through which anybody can share an email with everybody included in the mailing list. I think it's called "discussion list". I've searched online, but basically most of answers usually refer to marketing mailing lists. How do I find a valuable mailing-list of such type?

The mailing list is thought for sharing urban-regeneration related news through an open mailing-list of organizations: universities, privates, foundations. However, the mailing-list is not hosted by a university, and would like to understand a viable alternative. I have found this type of mailing-lists only in academic fields, and wanted to understand whether there was a way for anybody to setup such type of mailing list.

Since I may provide storage space through a server provider, my question includes advice on both ready-made options, as well as third-party applications that could be linked to a specific proprietary website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for mailing list software. There various such are programs, the most common and advanced ones are:

- [Sympa](https://www.sympa.org/)
- [GNU Mailman](https://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/)
- [Wikipedia has a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mailing_list_software)

You can configure these programs as you like, for announcements (only a few people can post), for discussions (everybody can post, with or without moderation), filtering, etc. Refer to the software's documentation for more details.